# ¿Cómo recupero en Visual Studio las pestañas superiores de archivo, vistas, ...? las deshabilite y con F11 no las recupero

Tags: visual

Necesito recuperar las pestañas superiores del programa *Visual Studio* lo deshabilite y ahora no se como recuperarlo de nuevo.

Comment: Trata siempre de agregarle valor a tus respuestas, como una imagen, respondí infiriendo en lo que pueda suceder.

Answer (score 0):

dentro de Visual Studio Code, dale la tecla <kbd>Alt</kbd> , cuando te aparezca la pantalla siguiente marca Show Menu Bar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]